# Is there any way to protect some api that has no login requirement using laravel sanctum?

Tags: php, laravel

This is my first time using laravel sanctum. Before this, I use Laravel Passport for protecting the route.
So the problem is, there are 2 kind of route. Route that need user authentication, like API profile, my order, and inbox. And route that doesn't need user authentication to access, like API version control, splashscreen, and forgot password.
In my last project when using passport, in passport there was client token, that doesn't need user credential to get. Then I use auth_client middleware to protect route that doesn't need user authentication. First I want to ask, is this the correct way?

If that was correct way, and protecting no need login route is recommended, how i do the same thing using laravel sanctum?

Comment: why not just remove the non authenticated routes from the sanctum middleware??

Comment: I'm assuming you're talking about sanctum for token management. You can still do the same with sanctum i.e. issue a token for everyone who doesn't already have one and if a user signs then you can associate that token with that user.

Comment: @zahid, thats what i do now, but what i want to do is protect that route whit this sanctum mechanism

Comment: @apokryfos, how to issue a token for everyone/guest? I don't find any way to issue token without user related.

Comment: Create a single user with as a "guest" user and anyone who is not signed in can be signed in as this user, but be mindful not to allow this guest user to do anything that requires sign in.